# pointer-events: none is not working on IE10

Tags: javascript, html, angular-ui-router, internet-explorer-10

I have html like following

```
<li><a href="javascript:" ng-class="disabled" ui-sref="base" ui-sref-active="active" class="menu-item" >Base</a></li>
```

disabled class is

```
a.disabled {
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

It is working in chrome. but it is not working on IE10.

How can i solve this issue?

If possible. can we solve by css?

Comment: Is this even a valid approach for what you're trying to? Didn't try it, but wouldn't you still be able to activate the link using keyboard keys?

Comment: Also how about adding "disabled" to the parent li and adding a second dummy text as a child that's toggled together with the link to only show one of them based on state?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the click handler?

Comment: @Mario, I dont know correct approach for this one. Can you explain on same.

Comment: @SESN  I am not preventing click event on this.

Comment: So what's your actual goal? Just prevent the `::hover` selector to be applied?

Comment: I want to disable pointer events. It should be visible and less opacity.

Comment: [IE10 doesn't support `pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Browser_compatibility), it was added to version 11.